# Adapter Missing Error on iOS9 - PouchDB

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

In continuation of my previous posts relating to a failure while replicating the remote CouchDB - I used the FruitDown Adapter:

My code is like:

PouchDB and Adapter referencing done on index.html as follows:

```
<script src="lib/pouchdb/pouchdb-5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- FruitDown Adapter for iOS -->
<script src="lib/pouchdb/pouchdb.fruitdown.js"></script>
```

And a Factory that creates the Local & Remote data base references are as follows:

```
setLocalDb: function () {
    local_db_name = 'local_db';
    if (isIOS) {
         local_db = new PouchDB (local_db_name, {adapter: 'fruitdown'});
    } else {
         local_db = new PouchDB (local_db_name);
    }
}

setRemoteDb: function () {
    remote_db_name = 'remote_db';
    if (isIOS) {
        remote_db = new PouchDB ('http://my_remote_address', {
                    auth: {username: 'admin', password: 'admin123'}, adapter: 'fruitdown'});
    } else {
        remote_db = new PouchDB ('http://my_remote_address, {
                    auth: {username: 'admin', password: 'admin123'}
         });
    }
}
```

With the above code - when I call a `replicate()` method - the replication stops on the **PAUSE** block and Error shown as `'Error: Adapter is missing'`

Could you please guide where am I going wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that the `pouchdb.fruitdown.js` was not included on the page somehow. Can you double-check that it was loaded by printing out `PouchDB.preferredAdapters` or `Object.keys(PouchDB.adapters)`? It should contain `['idb', 'websql', 'fruitdown']`.

Comment: Hi Nolan .. I just tested with the following code:  `local_db = new PouchDB (local_db_name, {adapter: 'fruitdown'});          console.log(PouchDB.adapters);` it shows the `Object {}
fruitdown: LevelPouchAlt(opts, callback)`  @nlawson

Comment: Maybe the issue is applying `'fruitdown'` to the `remote_db`? You don't need to use FruitDOWN for a remote database, since it's using the `http` adapter instead.

Comment: Hi Nolan (@nlawson) I remoded the FruitDown adapter from `remote_db` reference but the Error remains same.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. Somehow the library is not being loaded. To prove that FruitDOWN works, here's a demo: http://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/401ef1fb44004d6cdaf1

Comment: I am using similar code. Do I need to inject the FruitDown as a dependency to my angular factory ?? Since I am using Angular..if yes could you guide how ?  But at the same time - how come the exact same code working just fine on Android ... not sure why  !!!  @nlawson

Comment: FruitDOWN uses a generic IndexedDB database, which is fully supported by Android and only partially supported by iOS. So it works on both platforms. As for Angular, I'm really not an expert, so I'm not sure what advice to give you, but most likely what you're missing is that `window.PouchDB` is not available when you load the plugin... if you don't have a global `window.PouchDB`, then you need to do `PouchDB.adapter(require('pouchdb/extras/fruitdown'))`. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Nolan .. I will give it a shot .. your comments and suggestions have helped me a lot. Thanks again @nlawson.